# Create custom widget as toolbar for QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, toolbar

I want to create a custom toolbar widget (something like a ribbon). Then I want to create a `QMainWindow` that uses this custom widget as its toolbar.

I can do something like

```
class RibbonToolbar : public QToolBar {
...
};

...


QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();
RibbonToolbar *toolbar = new RibbonToolbar(window);
window->addToolBar(toolbar);
```

The problem is that in this way `RibbonToolbar` inherits all methods from `QToolbar` and I don't want it because my widget does not use them. It's a completely new widget.

I'd like to do this:

```
class RibbonToolbar : public QWidget {
...
};
```

So if I declare my class in this way, what's the best way to add it to the top of the QMainWindow?

PS: My widget can be adapted if `QMainWindow` is resized but, like the ribbon in Microsoft Office, it's a fixed position so it can't move around into the main window.

Comment: A specific layout of a main window has hundreds lines of code to deal with toolbars. You will need to make a lot of efforts to achieve it with a custom widget and I bet that you find a lot of obstacles on this way. My suggestion is to customize QToolBar with CSS or with custom painting to look like you want but use the fuctionality of it.

Comment: Infact I don't want to rewrite it. I want only to know how can I inheriths a QToolbar without these issues.

Answer (score 0):

In `C++`, it is not possible to remove functionality from a class. However, it is possible to hide existing functionality.[(1)](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/116-adding-changing-and-hiding-members-in-a-derived-class/)

That being said, how about you hide `QToolBar` member functions that you don't want to use by declaring them `private`?

Let's use a `QWidget` as an example:

*widget.h:*

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    void setGeometry(const QRect &);
    void setGeometry(int x, int y, int w, int h);
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

*widget.cpp:*

```
#include "widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}

void Widget::setGeometry(const QRect &)
{
}

void Widget::setGeometry(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
}
```

In this case, even though `setGeometry` is a member function of `QWidget`, you can't use it in anymore from `Widget`. Similarly you could hide `QToolBar::isMovable` by declaring it private and provide an empty implementation for it.

Also more conveniently would be to declare them `protected` so that they will be accessible from derived classes if you want.

AFAIK you can't use

```
class RibbonToolbar : public QWidget {
...
};
```

because `QMainWindow` API is made in such way that it will accept only pointers to `QToolBar` for its toolbar areas. You could trick it by creating a `RibbonToolbar` which is binary compatible with `QToolBar` and `reinterpret_cast` the object to `QToolBar*` but then you would need to deeply know the inner guts of `Qt` and it would still be bad practice.

Comment: Maybe it can be a solution, even if a little verbose. I'll check it.

Comment: @Jepessen Please do so. I don't think you have another option.